# Get HWND on windows with Qt5 (from WId)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface, qt5

I am trying to convert a Qt4 Application to Qt5.
The only thing I couldn't figure out is how to get the *HWND* of a Widget.
The program uses [EcWin7](https://code.google.com/p/dukto/downloads/detail?name=EcWin7-1.0.2.zip&can=2&q=) to show the progress on the taskbar icon on win 7+ but expects a *HWND*. The lib itself seems to compile fine after changing *Q_WS_WIN* to *Q_OS_WIN*)
In Qt4 on Windows *WId* was just a typedef for *HWND*, so this was no problem.
In Qt5 this is not the case anymore.
I found some [mailing list posting](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.user/4895) that could give a clue but it seems *QPlatformNativeInterface* is not part of the public API of Qt5 anymore.

The program calls *EcWin7.init(this->winId());* and I need to some way to convert this ID into the *HWND* id or some other way to get this.

Comment: Well, that's strange. [QWidget::winId()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#winId) should return HWND on Windows, as it was in Qt4.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Qt5 `winEvent` was replaced by `nativeEvent`:

```
bool winEvent(MSG* pMsg, long* result)
```

is now

```
bool nativeEvent(const QByteArray & eventType, void * message, long *result)
```

And in `EcWin7::winEvent` you have to cast `void` to `MSG`:

```
bool EcWin7::winEvent(void * message, long * result)
{
    MSG* msg = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(message);
    if (msg->message == mTaskbarMessageId)
    {
      ...
```

I was able to get the application to work! Just replace:

```
 mWindowId = wid;
```

with

```
 mWindowId = (HWND)wid;
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, there are a lot of bugs. Not all events are passed to real widget, a lot of them are passed to top-level widget.

Answer (score 11):

```
#include <QtGui/5.0.0/QtGui/qpa/qplatformnativeinterface.h>

static QWindow* windowForWidget(const QWidget* widget) 
{
    QWindow* window = widget->windowHandle();
    if (window)
        return window;
    const QWidget* nativeParent = widget->nativeParentWidget();
    if (nativeParent) 
        return nativeParent->windowHandle();
    return 0; 
}

HWND getHWNDForWidget(const QWidget* widget)
{
    QWindow* window = ::windowForWidget(widget);
    if (window && window->handle())
    {
        QPlatformNativeInterface* interface = QGuiApplication::platformNativeInterface();
        return static_cast<HWND>(interface->nativeResourceForWindow(QByteArrayLiteral("handle"), window));
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: corroboration, and further details how to get this to compile:  http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2013-June/007650.html

Answer (score 3):

You may try:

```
(HWND)QWidget::winId();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this function: `QWindowsNativeInterface::nativeResourceForWindow`

Answer (score 2):

winId() worked for me on Qt 5.1
at least it has the same value when I'm using

```
bool Widget::nativeEvent(const QByteArray & eventType, void * message, long * result)
{
    MSG* msg = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(message);
    qDebug() << msg->hwnd;

    return false;
}
```

and

```
qDebug() << winId();
```