# Force QWidget Child to have its own Window Handle

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface, qt5

I am trying to create a small application using *Qt*. What I want to do is to display in a dock widget a 3D Interface using `DirectX11`, other widgets in the `QMainWindow` will have properties to modify the behavior of what is been displayed in `DX11`.

The problem I am facing is that when I add a `QDockWidget` to `QMainWindow`, the `dockWidgetContents` function `windowHandle` returns `NULL`.

I am using an example from [Get HWND on windows with Qt5 (from WId)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048565/get-hwnd-on-windows-with-qt5-from-wid) to get the `HWND`. But if the function return `NULL` it will go up and get the `HWND` of the `QMainWindow`.

Is there any way to force a `QWidget` to have its own window handle?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You have several options for that. See the topic **Native Widgets vs Alien Widgets** in the [QWidget class documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html).

> 1. Use the QT_USE_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1 in your environment.
> 2. Set the Qt::AA_NativeWindows attribute on your application. All widgets will be native widgets.
> 3. Set the Qt::WA_NativeWindow attribute on widgets: The widget itself and all of its ancestors will become native (unless Qt::WA_DontCreateNativeAncestors is set).
> 4. Call QWidget::winId to enforce a native window (this implies 3).
> 5. Set the Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen attribute to enforce a native window (this implies 3).

Comment: Making all widgets native is a bad idea, it will be a performance hog. Anything that does it is a no-no. The attribute needs to be set on the single widget in question.