# How to get the widget window handle to passed to win32 api MessageBox in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, qt5

In short, I want to use win32Api in `Qt5.1.1`, And I have a simple example.

I want to pass the widget handle to the WinApi function `int MessageBox(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType).`

The problem in the first parameter `(HWND hWnd, ...)`.

**My attempt: (Failed)**

```
WId wind = (HWND)w.winId(); // `w` is the instance of my widget.
MessageBox(wind, "Hello world!", "Message", MB_OK);
```

How to obtain the widget(window) handle, to passed to `MessageBox` winapi function ?

Comment: Why is the message outside of the widget? By having the message outside the widget its possible that the widget is closed when you call `MessageBox`.

Answer (score 1):

If your in Qt, all Widgets should have a `QWidget::winId()` function. Simply call `winId()` and you'll get the windows handle.

Comment: Those are link time errors. The compiler does not know where the definition of `MessageBox` and `MB_OK` are. You'll have to include `#include <windows.h>` at the top of the file that `MessageBox` is used.

Comment: Seems their is a change from Qt4 which I use to Qt5 which stops the convertion from working. Let me research it for a bit

Comment: @LionKing look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14500265/942596). It uses `::windowForWidget(widget);` which converts a widget to a `QWindow` and allows you access to the `handle()` method witch is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a function in qt5 like `winId()` to do that directly?

Comment: @LionKing Not that I know of, but try a simple cast `MessageBox((HWND)wind, "Hello world!", "Message", MB_OK);`. This should also work.

Comment: Unfortunately, still appears an error `error: C2664: 'MessageBoxW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from const char [13] to LPCWSTR
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast`

Comment: @LionKing Your making me work for the rep aren't you. You have UNICODE mode on. Add `#include <tchar.h>` and replace the message with `MessageBox((HWND)wind, _T("Hello world!"), _T("Message"), MB_OK);`

Comment: Thanks for continued help me, but Unfortunately, still the same last error.

Comment: @LionKing Same place or a different place? All string in your code should be wrapped with `_T()` macro.

Comment: Same place, `error: C2664: 'MessageBoxW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [13]' to 'LPCWSTR'
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast`

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get her to compile for you. But that's the limit of how much I know, Try to research the error, then ask a new question on it on stack about it.

Comment: For future reference, start the string with an `L` (i.e. `L"Hello, world"`)