# how can I obtain HWND of a class derived from QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I currently have a windows API that requires a `HWND hParentWnd`. My question is how can I obtain HWND of a class derived from `QMainWindow` ?

Comment: Similar question: [Get HWND on windows with Qt5 (from WId)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048565/get-hwnd-on-windows-with-qt5-from-wid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [QWidget::effectiveWinId()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#effectiveWinId) or [QWidget::winId()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#winId), this holds the HWND of the widget on Windows.

```
MainWindow w;
w.show();
HWND hWnd = (HWND) w.winId();
```