# Linux Message window

Tags: linux, messagebox

I need to display message window in Linux similar to one ( Winmain  ,Mainwndproc) in windows.I tried using x11 but i am not able to pass messages similar to sendmessage function in windows.

I need to replicate the same functionality in Linux.Any insights on how to implement?

Comment: Xwindows has nothing in common with windows, except being a "gui". stop thinking in windows terms.

Comment: Depends on your task. If it's programming task -- go ahead and use Qt or GTK+ framework. If it's ok to use bash -- you can stick to `zenity` or `kdialog` tools.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SendMessage of MFC equivalent in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351278/sendmessage-of-mfc-equivalent-in-qt)