# C++ Global Hotkeys with platform APIs

Tags: c++, qt, hotkeys, global-hotkey

I'm working on an application for taking screenshots on Windows, OSX and Linux in C++/Qt. Now I need to set global hotkeys, so the user can take screenshots when the application is running in the background. I tried with Qxt and UGlobalHotkey, which are both Qt libraries, but neither of them seemed to work.

I tried to implement it for OSX with Carbon [(tutorial)](http://dbachrach.com/blog/2005/11/program-global-hotkeys-in-cocoa-easily/), but I need to call a class member function, which just doesn't work. Could someone provide me with an example? You can find my code [here](https://github.com/mkocs/pixmate-client/blob/master/src/mainwindow.cpp). The function i need to call is new_screenshot().

Or is there any other way to achieve something like this? I really need my application to take a screenshot from the background, otherwise it's pretty useless (yes, I should probably have implemented it at the very beginning to see if it even works). Would it maybe be better to have a separate client for every platform (Cocoa Swift for OSX, GTK for Linux, C# client for Windows)? I have often thought about this the past few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you want  to call `new_screenshot` from the hot key event handler? If so, `InstallApplicationEventHandler` lets you pass a pointer to user data in 4th argument. Pass a pointer to your `MainWindow` instance (based on code from the tutorial):

```
MainWindow *mainWindow = ... // get main window somehow
InstallApplicationEventHandler(&MyHotKeyHandler,1,&eventType,mainWindow,NULL);
```

Then you can use it in the event handler.

```
OSStatus MyHotKeyHandler(EventHandlerCallRef nextHandler,EventRef theEvent, void *userData)
{
//Do something once the key is pressed
static_cast<MainWindow*>(userData)->new_screenshot();
return noErr;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. I should really start reading documentation. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. new_screenshot() never gets called. [This](https://gist.github.com/mkocs/26045dc924391a8e4166) is what I currently have.

Comment: I see that you don't set the `eventKind` member of the `EventTypeSpec`. Should be `kEventHotKeyPressed`.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you very much. May I ask where you found about how this works? I'm actually just trying to learn how to do some more complicated stuff and couldn't find any documentation about Carbon at all, since it seems to be deprecated.

Comment: I'm using `JFHotkeyManager` in my app. It's in Objective C, but should not be too hard to understand: https://github.com/jaz303/JFHotkeyManager

Answer (score 1):

I did something in the past with MFC and WIN32 API....so it only works on Windows...but pressing `ALT+F10` was able to hide/show a window...

```
void CWinHideDlg::OnButtonActive() 
{
    CString tmp;
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_BUTTON_ACTIVE,tmp);
    if(0 == strcmp(tmp.GetBuffer(tmp.GetLength()),"Activate"))
    {
        m_myAtom=GlobalAddAtom("MY_GLOBAL_HOT_HIDE_KEY");
        int err=RegisterHotKey(this->GetSafeHwnd(),m_myAtom,MOD_ALT,VK_F10);
        SetDlgItemText(IDC_BUTTON_ACTIVE,"Stop");
        CButton *pBtn = (CButton *)GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON_UNHIDE);
        pBtn->EnableWindow(TRUE);
        SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATIC_INFO,"Set the mouse over the window \nand press ALT + F10 to hide it...");
    }
    else
    {
        UnregisterHotKey(this->GetSafeHwnd(),m_myAtom);
        GlobalDeleteAtom(m_myAtom);     
        CButton *pBtn = (CButton *)GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON_UNHIDE);
        pBtn->EnableWindow(FALSE);
        SetDlgItemText(IDC_BUTTON_ACTIVE,"Activate");

    }   
}
```

Basically this code activates/deactivates the hot key `ALT+F10`, once it activates you can hide/unhide a running window on the system by setting the mouse pointer over the window and press `ALT+F10`...

This is from the `WindowProc` function:

```
if(message == WM_HOTKEY)
    {
        CString tmp;
        POINT pc;
        GetCursorPos(&pc);


        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F10))
        {
            HWND hwnd=::WindowFromPoint(pc);            
            if(hwnd)
            {
                tmp.Format("%08Xh",hwnd);
                m_HideWins.InsertString(m_HideWins.GetCount(),tmp);
                ::ShowWindow(hwnd,SW_HIDE);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can use the code to register your own HOT Key and use it to take a screenshot...

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think this will be very helpful, since I want to enable this feature on Windows, OSX and Linux. I already read about the RegisterHotkey function in windows API. But how does this->GetSafeHwnd() work? How would I get the HWND to pass?

Comment: this may give you the hwnd: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048565/get-hwnd-on-windows-with-qt5-from-wid[/link]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems to be just what I needed for Windows.

Comment: Great, Good Luck with your project.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction here? You seem to know a lot about this and I think my [code](https://gist.github.com/mkocs/dc0a5a122be4df593210) now works because it prints 0x16171fc0 every time I press my exact key combination, but my window never shows up. I guess this is because of the loop? How would I listen for the key combination without blocking the rest? Running it in a separate thread doesn't seem to work because it doesn't detect the hotkey combination anymore.